# Angularfire How getting all field names form a firestore document to an arraylist

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

How can I get fields name in Angularfire - firestore like [this android example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50701733/4654957)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which part has you struggling, but this is the basic approach using the JavaScript SDK:

```
var rootRef = firebase.firestore();
var codesRef = rootRef.collection("CodeClinic").document("Codes");
codeRef.get().then(function(document) {
  var data = document.data();
  console.log(Object.keys(data));
})
```

Since AngularFire is built on top of the JavaScript SDK, the above will work in AngularFire too and it will interop without problems.